# Extracting polynomial coefficients

Tags: python, sympy

I am solving a system of linear equations that can have multiple unknowns, at most four. The unknowns are:

```
['x', 'y', 'z', 'k'].
```

I have the following polynomial:

```
p = sy.Poly("9*x/20 - 9*z/20 - 3/5").
```

I want to write a code that will check if any of the coefficients x,y,z,k is missing from the polynomial. If yes, they should be replaced by a zero. If not, they should be extracted and appended to an empty list. I created a code as follows:

```
p = sy.Poly("9*x/20 - 9*z/20 - 3/5")
vars_in_p = p.gens

coefs = []
for var in ['x', 'y', 'z', 'k']:
    if var not in vars_in_p:
        coefs.append(0)
    else:
        coefs.append(p.coeff_monomial(var))
```

However, every time I print the coefs, it gives me the following result:

```
[0,0,0,0].
```

I would also like to add the coefficient that does not have any unknowns.

Comment: your have the wrong tag.  simpy is for discrete event simulation.  I think you want the tag sympy

Comment: @Michael yes, I wanted to tag sympy. It was a mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that p.gens returns a tuple of `sympy.core.symbol` not strings.

You have to get the names of the symbols to elaborate vars_in_p like below:

```
p = sy.Poly("9*x/20 - 9*z/20 - 3/5")
vars_in_p = [v.name for v in p.gens]

coefs = []
for var in ['x', 'y', 'z', 'k']:
    if var not in vars_in_p:
        coefs.append(0)
    else:
        coefs.append(p.coeff_monomial(var))
```

I get :

```
[9/20, 0, -9/20, 0]
```

Comment: Also, adding 1 to the variables would give us the constant term we wanted `for var in ['x', 'y', 'z', 'k', 1]`